# Using php to extract url and arguments

Tags: php, url

I am not exactly following the error that I'm having... I'm getting a blank output.   It's my goal to go my `mywebsite.com/test.php?location=1234&arg=5678` and get some kind of a hash-map set up with these (K/V relationship or even 2 arrays) and iterate through them.

Thanks.

Code:

```
    <?php
        function curPageURL() {
            $pageURL = 'http://';
            if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
                $pageURL.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            } else {
                $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            }
            return $pageURL;
        }

        $query = parse_url(curPageURL(), PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $params);
        $test = $params['test'];
        echo test;
    ?>
```

Comment: `echo test;`.. make `test` a variable ($)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

First, if you're running this on shared hosting, the host likely has errors turned off.  This results in a blank page in the case of fatal (or 500) errors.  Add this to the top of the file to see your errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Second, if your goal is to retrieve the parameters from the URL, PHP gives you an easy way to get there.  Use the $_GET superglobal, i.e.:

```
foreach ($_GET as $param => $value) {
    echo $param . " : " . $value . "<br/>";
}
```

MUCH simpler, no?

Comment: I would suggest to add error_reporting(E_ALL) as well as on production environments it could be set to not report any error from the php.ini sometimes

Comment: Good call.  I'll change it.

Comment: Very nicely done, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You're very welcome.  You may want to read up on the other superglobals.  You were already halfway there, $_SERVER is one of them.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php